# memory leak in singleton class

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, singleton

I am new to iPhone development.
I am developing an application in which I am using Single tone class.
When I am creating an object of single tone class it is giving me memory leak on analyzing my code. It is giving message as "Potential leak of an object" and "Allocated object is not referenced later". But I am using that object in my code.
following is my code where I have created single tone class object

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Inside View");
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Menu List";

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation_bar.png"];
    [_bgImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-45,320,510)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_bar.png"]];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];


    menuTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    menuTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    _hotelMenu=[SharedHotelMenu sharedInstanceMethod];
    _queryFormatter=[[DatabaseQueryFormatter alloc]init];

    _isSearchOn=NO;
    _searchResult=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    _categorySearch.layer.cornerRadius = 19;
    _categorySearch.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _categorySearch.delegate=self;

    UIView *_paddingView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,5,10)];
    _categorySearch.leftView=_paddingView;
    _categorySearch.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [_paddingView release];

    UIView *_paddingRightView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,10)];
    _categorySearch.rightView=_paddingRightView;
    _categorySearch.rightViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [_paddingRightView release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(searchBar)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:_categorySearch];
}
 }
```

I have created single tone class object as _hotelMenu=[SharedHotelMenu sharedInstanceMethod];

Comment: Are you sure you are getting leaks because of this..Can you post the screen shot?

Comment: if you are not using ARC, then you must release the object you alloc.for example `_queryFormatter=[[[DatabaseQueryFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];` will reduce one warning for sure

Comment: In my single tone class while returning object it is giving message as "Object with +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1(owing) retain count is expected". I am getting this message for following block of code in single tone class                       + (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [[self sharedInstanceMethod] retain];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in your code is that this line may cause memory leak

```
menuTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

As this is `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableFooterView` and it will retain your object and thus retain count becomes 2.

Use this

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
menuTableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
[footerView release];
```